# jQuery: Add/remove text string to src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I'm trying to append a string of text to the `src` attribute of an image on `mouseover` and then remove that string on `mouseout`. Right now I have it half working:

**Javascript**

```
$('.singleSidebar .subnav img').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', function(index, attr) {
    return attr.replace(/\.[^.]*$/, '_anim$&');
    });
});
```

I found this code somewhere else and so I'm not exactly sure how to modify it to remove the string `_anim` on `mouseout`.

Comment: Ha, I'm not sure. I found this somewhere. There is likely a cleaner way.

Comment: Instead of posting random code that you found, give a thorough description of what you want to do, including the before/after result desired for your attribute value.

Comment: I'd personally create 2 `img` objects and swap between them rather than try and change the Url - which relies on browser caching amongst other things

Comment: @ Bergi - LOL. @colindunnn Simply do `var newSrc = $(this).attr('src');` - Then you can reference the SRC, split it on the underscore, and use whatever came before the underscope. `newSrc = newSrc.split('_');` - This will break the SRC into an array. Everything before the underscore will be [0] based, everything after the underscore is [1] based. At this point, you can do `$(this).attr('src', 'newSrc[0]')` - and this will be what you want.

Comment: @basic that does sounds better, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest just loading both images and then only showing the one you want. This can all be accomplished with CSS.

Give one image a class of "animated" and the other class of "nonanimated". Add this CSS to handle the onhover change:

```
    .singleSidebar .subnav img.animated,
    .singleSidebar .subnav img.nonanimated:hover
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .singleSidebar .subnav img.animated:hover,
    .singleSidebar .subnav img.nonanimated
    {
        display: block
    }
```

This will work better because the browser will load the image right away instead of when you hover your mouse, it's also a bit cleaner IMO

EDIT
Ah, if you need them to start playing on hover then you will need to do it your way. Try something like this:

```
$('.singleSidebar .subnav img').each(function(e){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).hover(function(){
      $(this).attr('src', src.replace('.gif', '_anim.gif'));
    }, function(){
      $(this).attr('src', src);
    });
  });
```

​

Comment: On second thought, the problem with this approach is the GIFs will start playing immediately on page load, rather than on mouseover.

Comment: Ah, I EDIT my answer with a new solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".singleSidebar .subnav img").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).attr('src', function(index, attr) {
      return attr.replace(/\.[^.]*$/, '_anim$&');
    });
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).attr('src', function(index, attr) {     
        return attr.replace('_anim', ''); // or any other replace
    }); 
  }
);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/hover/ for more information

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/dZ3c2/1/

```
var src;
$("img").hover(function() {
     src = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).attr("src", "replacementsrc");
},function() {
     $(this).attr("src", src);
});​
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I can't get it to work with the `.append` attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/EGCyE/

Comment: @colindunnn what element are you trying to append to (other element)? i don't see? :)

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use .mouseout and reverse the replace.

```
$('.singleSidebar .subnav img').mouseout(function(){     
    $(this).attr('src', function(index, attr) {     
        return attr.replace(/_anim$/, '');     
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Though +1 to Basic's comment above.  Swapping images is a much better idea than changing the src.